# deterministic uuidv4 -> uuidv4

Tags: hash, collision-resistance, entropy

I need to copy a graph of elements with `uuidv4`s each, and separately stored relations containing element `uuidv4`s.

On copy, I need to change the ids. Of course all relation ids should still point to the correct corresponding location in the copy.

So I need a deterministic `f(uuidv4): uuidv4` function.

I can work with a temporarily cached lookup table. But I wonder if there's a hashing function with the same result? This would give the added benefit of establishing a free relation between the original and the copy, which I otherwise will have to model as another relation.

E.g. I could create a new `uuidv4` from a truncated `sha256` output of the original `uuidv4`. But it does seem to violate the idea of random uuids for getting the necessary entropy.. Are there some thoughts on how the entropy may be affected?

Comment: If the whole graph fits in RAM, then the look up table will probably be faster. Entropy is a red herring. If you make a copy of the graph (differing only by ID values) and the process is deterministic then the entropy of the distribution of output graphs **necessarily** is the same as the entropy of the inputs' distribution.

Comment: Collisions are a concern when you use a truncated hash. Brute forcing collisions for outputs lengths of 128-bits or fewer is something modern computers could do. You could almost do a collision-free transformation using an ordinary 128-bit wide block cipher. However, not all 128-bit values are valid UUID v4 values. Simple format preserving encryption solves that problem. Yes, block ciphers are not one-way, but you can just choose a random key then erase each remaining copy of the key from memory after the graph is copied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java's internal secure random generator works along similar principles, just uses the older SHA1. By rehashing a starting point (seed), you create a ersatz cryptographically secure pseudo random number generator (CSPRNG).  Albeit, you're only creating one output per seed.

The entropy isn't really affected and truncation is okay as we consider all of the SHA256 output bits as independent.  Unless you have very particular requirements and used a true random number generator, the likelihood is that the UUIDs were originally generated by some form of CSPRNG from the underlying OS.  You're just adding another round of processing.

The number of random  UUIDs (of 122 random bits) which need to be generated in order to have a 50% probability of at least one collision is $\approx 2^{\frac{n}{2}}$ or $\approx 2 \times 10^{18}$. There's a little bit more in the wiki [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Collisions).

Comment: +/- 0 vote. Entropy is actually irrelevant. Only whether collisions happen matters (because that would change the graph after relabling nodes). Reasoning by relating hash input/output to RNG seed/output is faulty but coincidentally, in this case, comes to the right conclusion anyway. Related keys (or seeds) *may* be a problem for a generic PRNG, PRF, PRP. For a sane SHA-2 based implementation it wouldn't be a problem, because SHA-256 pretty much looks like an ideal random function in practice. But then the solution can be simplified to just talk about SHA-2, not an RNG.